# Add product short-description on product review page in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I am using

```
$_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getShortDescription()), 'short_description');
```

in catalog/product/view.phtml to show the product short description.

It is showing in single product page but not in product review page though enabling Template Path Hints shows they both come from view.phtml

Any suggestions?

Comment: great solution. it is working for me

Answer (score 2):

There are some  `logical  implementation avalibale` on magento.

I have seen in class `Mage_Review_Block_Product_View`  the `short description` is set as null .
I have comment that code .Now it working

So copy `app/code/core/Mage/Review/Block/Product/View.php`
to `app/code/local/Mage/Review/Block/Product/View.php`
and edit

```
 protected function _toHtml()
    {
        $this->getProduct()->setShortDescription(null);

        return parent::_toHtml();
    }
```

to

```
 protected function _toHtml()
    {
        //$this->getProduct()->setShortDescription(null);

        return parent::_toHtml();
    }
```

Or Enable short_description to used  in product list from `Admin>Catalog>Manage Attribute`

Comment: Changing to Mage::helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getShortDescription()), 'short_description');

doesn't help  and Used in Product Listing for short_description is already enabled.